# Is the set of coefficient functionals from the dual of a finite dimensional Banach space linearly independent?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let's say we have a finite dimensional Banach space $\mathcal{B}$ with $n$ basis functions $f_1,\ldots,f_n$. Given the dual space $\mathcal{B}^*$, there is a set of functionals $f_1^*,\ldots,f_n^*\in \mathcal{B}^*$ such that for any $f\in \mathcal{B}$, we can express it as
\begin{align*}
f&=\sum_{i=1}^n f_i^*(f) f_i.
\end{align*}
I presume the $f_i^*$ are linearly independent and span $\mathcal{B}^*$, right? If so, why?

Comment: Banach is useless. Just take a finite dimensional vector space (over any field).

Comment: "If so, why?" You seem to be asking for a proof. If so, please first edit your post to include your attempts and where you are stuck. First, prove (easily) the independence. https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask . Alternatively, open any textbook on linear algebra.